# Хранимая функция на С для PostgreSQL

Tags: c, postgresql

мне нужно написать хранимую функции на C для PostgreSQL 10 в Windows 10. Как писать саму функцию я разобрался, но проблема в том, что я не понимаю как скомпилировать.

```
gcc -I"path" -fpic -c name.c
```

из ошибок: `#error must have a working 64-bit integer datatype`

Вычитал что можно сделать все это в VS, но все примеры для VS10 и я натыкаюсь на множество ошибок.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне скомпилировать мою функцию.

P.S.:Я только в начале своего карьерного пути(студент) и это мой первый вопрос)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gcc -I%PATH_TO_POSTGRES_DIR%\include\server\port\win32 ^
    -I%PATH_TO_POSTGRES_DIR%\include\server ^
    -I%PATH_TO_POSTGRES_DIR%\include ^
    -shared -o hello.dll hello.c -DHAVE_LONG_LONG_INT_64
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ.Функция скомпилировалась, но при создании функции в PgAdmin происходит ошибка:
ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/lib/utils.dll": %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

SQL state: XX000
Подскажите, пожалуйста,как мне ее исправить

Comment: @СергейЧерных компилятор и СУБД одной разрядности?

Comment: gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)    
PostgreSQL 10.5, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit

Comment: Странно. Ваш код никакие библиотеки не использует?

Comment: Попробуйте экспорты убрать.

Comment: в include только postgres.h и fmgr.h
 Вот код функции: https://pastebin.com/agx0itcS

Comment: Я не могу воспроизвести вашу проблему, у меня такой же код успешно работает. Однако строки с 10 по 14 точно не нужны, макрос `PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1` и так объявляет экспорты должным образом.

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85505/discussion-between-sergey-chernykh-and-sergey-gornostaev).